# Function for copying arrays in Go language

Tags: arrays, go

Is there any built-in function in Go for copying one array to another?
Will this work in case of two (or more) dimensional arrays?

Comment: Pitfall: arrays and slices can look pretty similar, the behavior is different. Arrays are by value, slices by reference (simplified).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

> Is there any built-in function in Go language for copying one array to another?

Yes: http://play.golang.org/p/_lYNw9SXN5

```
a := []string{
    "hello",
    "world",
}
b := []string{
    "goodbye",
    "world",
}

copy(a, b)

// a == []string{"goodbye", "world"}
```

---

> Will this work in case of two (or more) dimensional arrays?

`copy` will do a shallow copy of the rows: http://play.golang.org/p/0gPk6P1VWh

```
a := make([][]string, 10)

b := make([][]string, 10)
for i := range b {
    b[i] = make([]string, 10)
    for j := range b[i] {
        b[i][j] = strconv.Itoa(i + j)
    }
}

copy(a, b)

// a and b look the same

b[1] = []string{"some", "new", "data"}

// b's second row is different; a still looks the same

b[0][0] = "apple"

// now a looks different
```

I don't think there's a built-in for doing deep-copys of multi-dimensional arrays: you can do it manually like: http://play.golang.org/p/nlVJq-ehzC

```
a := make([][]string, 10)

b := make([][]string, 10)
for i := range b {
    b[i] = make([]string, 10)
    for j := range b[i] {
        b[i][j] = strconv.Itoa(i + j)
    }
}

// manual deep copy
for i := range b {
    a[i] = make([]string, len(b[i]))
    copy(a[i], b[i])
}

b[0][0] = "apple"

// a still looks the same
```

edit: As pointed out in the comments, I assumed by "copy an array" you meant "do a deep copy of a slice", as arrays can be deep-copied with the `=` operator as per jnml's answer (because arrays are value types): http://play.golang.org/p/8EuFqXnqPB

Comment: You've answered the question: "Is there any built-in function in Go language for copying one slice to another?" Which might be what the OP actually wanted but you should explain the difference between arrays and slices.

Answer (score 22):

The primary "function" for copying an array in Go is the [assignment operator =](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments), as it is the case for any other value of any other type.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
        var a, b [4]int
        a[2] = 42
        b = a
        fmt.Println(a, b)

        // 2D array
        var c, d [3][5]int
        c[1][2] = 314
        d = c
        fmt.Println(c)
        fmt.Println(d)
}
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/pjrEUmNP6u)

---

Output:

```
[0 0 42 0] [0 0 42 0]
[[0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 314 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0]]
[[0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 314 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0]]
```

Comment: If you are using an actual array (not something created with `make()`, then assignment works perfectly well.

However, if you're dealing with slices (which I can see how some would be confused by the difference) then you'll need to explicitly `copy()`, or else you will have a reference type with pointers causing issues.

Comment: If you're dealing with a function parameter that is an "array", it is actually a slice and like @bvarner said, you need to explicitly call `copy()` if you don't want to mutate that parameter also when you mutate the "copy"

Answer (score 10):

Use `copy` http://play.golang.org/p/t7P6IliMOK

```
a := []int{1, 2, 3}
var b [3]int

fmt.Println("A:", a)
fmt.Println("B:", b)

copy(b[:], a)

fmt.Println("A:", a)
fmt.Println("B2:", b)

b[1] = 9

fmt.Println("A:", a)
fmt.Println("B3:", b)
```

OUT:

```
A: [1 2 3]
B: [0 0 0]
A: [1 2 3]
B2: [1 2 3]
A: [1 2 3]
B3: [1 9 3]
```